# Execute Image.onload before upload function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular and I have a function that does the image input.

Through the inserted images, I remove them information like name, size ...
My problem is that when uploading the image (I will need to know its height and width) the upload function is executed first than the function where I get the information from that image.

As a problem I get an undefined in width and height.

The upload function is performed first than image.onload :(

Does anyone know why?

**Component.ts**

```
  detectFiles(event) {       
    var files = event.target.files;
    if (files.length < 8) {
      for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {

        const item: any = {
          filename: event.target.files[index].name.split('.')[0],
        };

        this.filename = item.filename;
        this.items.push(item);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          item.url = e.target.result;
          const image = new Image();
          image.src = e.target.result;
          image.onload = function () {
            item.sizeH = image.width;

          };

        }
        formData.append('file', files[index]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because onload is asyncronous, and while `onload()` is still running, the script continues execution and reaches `upload`.

You can refactor your code, by moving your upload code into it's own function, and then calling it from inside of the `onload()` like this:

```
detectFiles(event) {
...
if (files.length < 8) {
    ...
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      ...
      image.onload = function() {
         ...
         uploadFile(formData, stamp, encrPath, sizeH, sizeV); // < Call the upload here
      };
    };
    ...
    }
}

uploadFile(formData, stamp, encrPath, sizeH, sizeV) {
  this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function(result) {
    self.uploadService
      .postImage(formData, stamp, encrPath, sizeH, sizeV)
    ...
  });
}
```